# Read component state from another component

Tags: react-native

i am quite new to react native development. I did some research but did not get working what i am trying to achieve. My *.js File has two components. One is a component for a star rating. The other contains the basic view. Inside the View I added a button. What I want to happen is that when a user taps the button, the input from the textfield (alredy working) and the current rating is collected for to be send via email.

Questions:
1) Can this only be achieved by implementing a flux pattern / using redux?
2) If yes: Does all the redux component (actions, reducer, store) have to be spit in separate files?
3) If no: How?

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import StarRating from 'react-native-star-rating';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export class GeneralStarExample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      starCount: 4
    };
  }

  onStarRatingPress(rating) {
    this.setState({
      starCount: rating
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StarRating
        disabled={false}
        maxStars={5}
        rating={this.state.starCount}
        selectedStar={(rating) => this.onStarRatingPress(rating)}
        starColor={'gold'}
        emptyStarColor={'gold'}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default class FeedbackView  extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
  }

  render () {
    return(

      <View style={styles.container}>
      <GeneralStarExample onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}/>
      <View style ={styles.textinput}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 240, width: 300, alignSelf: 'center', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
          />
      </View>
      <Button onPress={() => Actions.refresh({text: this.state.text, rating: this.props.rating})}>Senden</Button>
      <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
      <Text>{this.props.rating}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Thanks a lot,
Defrian

Comment: You don't need Flux/Redux to do anything— that's for sure :) They are completely optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You don't necessarily need to implement Redux or any Flux-like architecture but it's a very good approach in my opinion. Redux would help you keep your code clean and scalable.

2) Sure you can put all those in one file. Your Reducers and the Actions are basically just functions. As for the Store, all you need to create it a call to `createStore()` from the redux module.